# Must PowerShell scripts be called using only a single line?

Tags: command-line, powershell, parameters

I have some PowerShell scripts that accept many long parameters, like,

```
myScript.ps1 -completePathToFile "C:\...\...\...\file.txt" -completePathForOutput "C:\...\...\...\output.log" -recipients ("me@me.com") -etc.
```

I can't seem to make PowerShell run such scripts unless all the parameters are on a single line.  Is there a way to invoke the script more like this?

```
myScript.ps1
  -completePathToFile "C:\...\...\...\file.txt"
  -completePathForOutput "C:\...\...\...\output.log"
  -recipients (
    "me@me.com",
    "him@him.com"
   )
  -etc
```

The lack of readability is driving me nuts, but the scripts really do need to be this parametric.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PowerShell thinks the command is complete at the end of the line unless it sees certain characters like a pipe, open paren or open curly.  Just put a line continuation character `` ` at the end of each line but make sure there are no spaces after that continuation character:

```
myScript.ps1 `
  -completePathToFile "C:\...\...\...\file.txt" `
  -completePathForOutput "C:\...\...\...\output.log" `
  -recipients (
    "me@me.com", `
    "him@him.com" `
   )
```

If you're on PowerShell 2.0 you can also put those parameters in a hashtable and use splatting e.g:

```
$parms = @{
    CompletePathToFile   = 'C:\...\...\...\file.txt'
    CompletPathForOutput = 'C:\...\...\...\output.log'
    Recipients           = 'me@me.com','him@him.com'
}
myScript.ps1 @parms
```

Comment: I've found that the comma operator is enough to make Powershell continue to the next line, SO LONG AS it's actually parsing it as an operator and not a string parameter that ends in ','

Comment: Thanks.  I'm sure there other characters indicate to PowerShell there's more.  Not sure there is a documented list of these.

Comment: Keith, thanks for remininding me there is a splatting in Posh. I read it and then forget. Now I see that it brings a lot of possibilities of how to work with script/function parameters.